# Bing search results shows an HTML encoded ampersand instead of an actual ampersand

Tags: seo, bing, search-results

I've looked through Bing Webmaster Tools to see if there is a way I can fix this, but I haven't found anything.

Here is an example in the search results. The first link is the one in question.

[image]

Comment: Please include a screenshot, or copy the title, as search engine results (and your title) could change.

Comment: FWIW, for me Bing displays the ampersand correctly. Did you try some other sites? E.g., search for `Simon & Garfunkel` -- does it show the ampersand correctly for you?

Comment: I work for the company in question

Comment: What do you mean? Does Bing show the ampersand for results about `Simon & Garfunkel` correctly for you?

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be a bug in Bing, but there may be a work around.

The only way that Bing should show `&amp;` to users is if the source code for your title's source code had `&amp;amp;`.

To be correct, the HTML for your title should read:

```
<title>Charles &amp; Colvard</title>
```

but it currently reads:

```
<title>Charles & Colvard</title>
```

Technically your title is not well formed HTML because ampersands should be escaped.  This may be confusing Bing.  Change the title of your page to escape the ampersand in the HTML source code:

- It will still appear to users as "Charles & Colvard"
- It might not confuse Bing anymore

Comment: I'll give it a try, I actually had most of the ampersands encoded, but changed them all after this was brought to my attention.  Is there anyway for force bing to crawl the site again?

Comment: The cached copy of your site that they have has it unencoded now.  You can use [fetch as bingbot](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/fetch-as-bingbot-fe18fa0d) in the bing webmaster tools to force them to grab it.